# Как вставить метод внутрь метода самым простым способом?

Tags: java

Нужно вставить метод f внутрь метода task3 (потому что f используется только в task3). Напрямую не получается, intellijIDEA ругается. Я видел в интернете разные способы, они все слишком мудрёные. Мне по учёбе в универе это надо, поэтому нужен самый простой способ.
Спасибо.

```
class MyClass{

public static void task3(){
        //a=1, b=2, c=-15, d=14

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Коэффициенты уравнения
        System.out.println("Введите a, b, c, d");
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        int b = scanner.nextInt();
        int c = scanner.nextInt();
        int d = scanner.nextInt();

        if(a == 0 || d == 0){
            System.out.println("a и d не должны быть равны нулю!");
            return;
        }
        int i = 1;
        int iters = Math.abs(d)/2;

        // пока счётчик меньше половины d
        while (i <=  iters ) {
            // если счётчик является делителем d
            if (d % i == 0) {
                if (f(a, b, c, d, i) == 0) // и в то же время является корнем уравнения
                { System.out.println("Положительный корень: " + i); }
                if (f(a, b, c, d, -i) == 0) // если противоположное число тоже является корнем
                {System.out.println("Отрицательный корень: " + -i); }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

// вычисляет: ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d с коэффициентами и иксом ↓
    public static int f(int a, int b, int c, int d, int x)
    {return (a * x * x * x) + (b * x * x) + (c * x) + d; }

}
```

Comment: В джаве НЕЛЬЗЯ определить метод внутри метода.  Однако можно определить локальный класс. 
 Самый простой способ у вас написан, более мудреные будут включать рвзные варианты лямбд, типа функция от 5 аргументов (a. b, c, d, x), или от x и массива параметров.

Comment: А какие разные способы вы видели, интересно. Тут основа то одна, только передавать можно по разному, точнее просто выглядить будет по разному. То есть в любом случае нужен интерфейс функциональный, в методе в аргумент указываем его, и передаём уже либо анонимный класс имплементящий этот интерфейс, либо используем упрощённый вариант анонимного класса - лямбду, либо ссылку ::, то есть синтаксический сахар

Comment: то что один метод вызывается только из другого — еще не повод объединять код

Answer (score 0):

[Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Определяете:

```
Function<Integer, Integer> f = x -> (a * x * x * x) + (b * x * x) + (c * x) + d;
```

Вызываете:

```
y = f.apply(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно ещё с интерфейсом и анонимным классом извратиться:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyMethod<String, String> myMethod = new MyMethod<>() {
        @Override
        public String execute(String... args) {
            return String.join(" ", args);
        }
    };

    System.out.println(myMethod.execute("My", "method", "in", "action", "."));
}

public interface MyMethod<T, D> {
    T execute(D...args);
}
```

вывод

```
My method in action .
```

Тип возвращаемого значения, количество и типы входящих аргументов взяты чисто для примера, их можно кастомизировать как необходимо.

Но честно говоря, зачем в данном случае вообще нужено определять отдельный метод в методе? Вынести самостоятельный кусок функционала из метода это норм подход. (Uncle Bob рекомендует).  На худой конец, почему данный блок кода не может работать в этом методе без выноса наружу и без определения отдельного метода. Просто определие метода внутри метода и не передавать его куда-то, хотя бы в виде collback-а (типа как runnable) -это чёт странное.

Ну и уж если на то пошло и, прости Господи, определять так метод внутри, то можно вообще обойтись без аргументов и использовать переменные из метода

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "My";
    String str2 = "method";
    MyMethod<String> myMethod = new MyMethod<>() {
        @Override
        public String execute() {
            return String.format("%s %s", str1, str2);
        }
    };

    System.out.println(myMethod.execute());
}

public interface MyMethod<T> {
    T execute();
}
```

вывод

```
My method
```

будет, типа замыкания, но только ничего не замыкая, т.к. ничего никуда не передаётся.